# Log4j.properties file not found on classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, logging

I have been looking into this problem for couple days and I can't seem to figure out the answer..

I am using
- Spring 4.0.0 GA
- Tomcat-apache-7
- Apache Maven 3.1.1

I am building a Spring MVC app and I am incorporating Log4j.properties in the src/main/resources folder, or the class path folder. For some reason, it is not reading the properties file but instead  it uses the default Log4j.properties file in apache-tomcat-7/local/lib/Log4j.properties.

`log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@417c6323.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@417c6323 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@417c6323.
log4j: Using URL [file:/Users/Jacky/Sequoia/Local/apache-tomcat-7/lib/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/Users/Jacky/Sequoia/Local/apache-tomcat-7/lib/log4j.properties`

I have Log4j-1.2.17 jar and 
sl4j-api-1.7.5 api jar installed.

I Understand that I can manually set the path to -Dlog4j.configuration={path to file} but I believe there's a bigger problem here that I'm not seeing.

Can anyone give me some guidance or hints to go about this? what can be the problem

****Edit:****
Typo on the default log4j.properties file: The path is actually local/apache-tomcat-7/lib/log4j.properties.

The log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA
log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.file=${catalina.base}/logs/tomcat.log
log4j.appender.CATALINA.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.append=true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
```

The log4j.properties file is running properly and the ${catalina.base}/logs/tomcat.log is outputting to the expected folder.

Comment: Can you confirm that the log4j.properties file is properly deployed along with your web app?

Comment: What is that local folder?  I'm using tomcat 7 and I don't have that path.  My guess is it's using that log4j.properties because it's on the classpath before your war is.

Comment: The log4j.properties file in the apache-tomcat-7/local/lib/Log4j.properties is deployed properly along with my app. I apologize about the confusion of path. The path is actually local/apache-tomcat-7/lib/Log4j.properties

Comment: If Log4J is loaded by Tomcats classloader it cannot read your log4j.properties file in your application. Make sure that you don't have a log4j.jar somewhere in your tomcat installation but only in your war file.

Comment: Is the file called 'log4j.properties' or 'Log4j.properties' with a capital?

Comment: Where is the file you *actually want your web application to load*?

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out! I figure out the problem. I was using Tomcat 7.0.14 version and when I updated to a more recent version (Tomcat 7.0.47) Tomcat is able to read my log4j files in my target folder.